# Inheritance of a private method and Late Static Binding in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, private-methods, late-static-binding

So I've been reading official PHP documentation on [Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and came across a confusing example:

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "success!\n";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
   /* foo() will be copied to B, hence its scope will still be A and
    * the call be successful */
}

class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
        /* original method is replaced; the scope of the new one is C */
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
$c = new C();
$c->test();   //fails
?>
```

The output of the example:

```
success!
success!
success!


Fatal error:  Call to private method C::foo() from context 'A' in /tmp/test.php on line 9
```

Can someone please explain why the private method foo() gets copied to B? As far as I know only public and protected properties get copied to child class. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the comment "foo() will be copied to B" is a bit confusing or interpreted incorrectly. foo() is still private to A and can only be accessed from methods within A.

ie. In the example if you try to execute`$b->foo()` its will still fail as expected.

This is as I explained the example to myself and maybe will be helpful for others:

**Considering class B.**

`$b->test()` is able to access foo() as a public member of A.

`$this->foo()` also succeeds within `$b->test()`

`$static::foo()` succeeds because it is calling the version of foo() defined in A, from test() which is also defined in A. No scoping conflict.

**Considering class B.**

When foo() is overridden in class C, 
`$c->test()` of course is still accessible as a public member if A.

and within `$c->test()` $this->foo() is accessible as a private member of A. - all good.

BUT
`$static::foo()` is now trying the access from A, the version of foo() defined in class C and so fails because it is private in C. - as per the error message.

Comment: Hi @bcperth +1 thanks. "$static::foo() succeeds because it is calling the version of foo() defined in A, from test() which is also defined in A. No scoping conflict" - but why does it execute that of "A" if static:: be resolved to "B"?